# Select records in the future only

Tags: mysql

I have a number of events that circulate throughout a year. I need to select only the ones that have a future date. They all have a date associated with them in "date" format 000-00-00.

How do I add that to my query?

```
SELECT * FROM EVENTS WHERE EVENT_DATE > NOW() ???
```

Comment: Did you try this query? If your `EVENT_DATE` is indeed a proper MySQL DATETIME, it will work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User CURDATE() instead as this will be in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Edit, now that Michael mentioned that if the column is in the DATETIME format the query you have should work.

Answer (score 0):

how about SELECT * FROM EVENTS WHERE EVENT_DATE > CURDATE() ???